# Adding Multiple events hovertext in fullcalendar

Tags: jquery

My task is to display Multiple events on a day.I am using Jquery Full calendar, on mouseOver it has to display what all the events present on that particular day.The problem what i am facing is,If there are 3events on 16-01-2014 and 2events on 17-01-2014 but for 17-01-2014 its taking 3events and one is undefined.I want only 2events to be displayed on 17-01-2014.
Thanks in advance

My part of the code is here,entire code goes in http://jsfiddle.net/h9cC6/408/

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

    var events_array = [
        {
             title: "Event",
             start:'2014-01-16',
             tip1:"long event",
             tip2:"medium",
             tip3:"short event",

        },
        {
             title: "Event",
             start:'2014-01-17',
             tip1:"Someday",
             tip2:"Importantday",
             ...
        },
        ...
    ];

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's due to the way you create your tooltip:

```
var tooltip = '<div class="tooltipevent" style=background:#ccc;position:absolute;>' + calEvent.tip1+"<br>" + calEvent.tip2 +"<br>"+ calEvent.tip3+' </div>';
    $("body").append(tooltip);
```

it should be something like so:

```
var tooltip = '<div class="tooltipevent" style=background:#ccc;position:absolute;>';
if (calEvent.tip1) tooltip += calEvent.tip1+"<br>";
if (calEvent.tip2) tooltip += calEvent.tip2+"<br>";
if (calEvent.tip3) tooltip += calEvent.tip3+"<br>";
tooltip += ' </div>';
    $("body").append(tooltip);
```